# VS2008 how do I find the exact location of a class definition (from metadata)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll, editor

I am using VS2008 and an AddIn to create a web service.
The tool also creates code to access remote procedures (in fact this is another web service).

In the created code some classes are used which will contain the response. So it is a very nice solution.

Now to my problem:  When I use 'Goto definition' function, it shows me the class 'extracted from metadata'. So I guess it compiled the class into some library.

Now I would like to know the DLL where the class is defined.

How can this be achieved? To be honest, I manually checked the DLL and either I am getting old or there is some magic in how VS locates classes.

Could someone please give me a kick/hint in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I found out myself. It is too easy:

First, I hover the cursor over the tab header and it gives me the location of the DLL. Although this DLL is not part of the project, within the .svc file, the class is known as the declaring DLL is in the bin folder of the web service project.

I find this very strange as I thought that only files being part of the project (i.e. included) or libaries in the GAC are used for name resolving.

Anyway, I learned something new today, which is not part as all.